# Is it considered cheating if I purchase an essay but then don't use it?

Tags: ethics, cheating

According to one of my friend's suggestion, I visited a website and was going to find some tutoring support, then I ended up hiring a person to write the essay.

However, I changed my mind and I did work on the essay by myself without reading the bought essay. I am going not to come back to the website again. So if I just hired the essay writer but am not using their work, am I called a cheater? If I pay for a writer am I already cheating, or only when I use their work?

Comment: As you say, you have not used any of the bought essay - so, no, you are not a cheater - by the looks of it, you chose to write the essay honestly in the end - even at a financial cost to yourself. A question, how did you pay for the essay?

Comment: As an aside: It might be a good idea to report this website to stop other people being tempted to cheat. Websites offering to write people's essays for them can only ever bring trouble.

Comment: @Pharap What do you mean by reporting? To whom? And what do you expect to come of of that?

Comment: Is it considered murder if I buy a gun and bullets but then don't kill anyone?

Comment: Why did you hire someone to write an essay in the first place?

Comment: @Alizter I follow my friend's suggestion

Comment: @AntoniNguyen Do you not think that merely considering it is a very big problem in the way you view your education?

Comment: Another spin on it, still involving "cheating".  If I start talking to a girl online and decide to meet her in a hotel room, but in the end I don't go, my wife is still going to feel like I cheated if she finds out.  Just the fact that I talked to the other girl and went so far as to schedule a meeting would be devastating.  So, to Alizter's point, you have _mind-cheated_ - as my wife would put it.

Comment: but in fact, i submitted the my own essay, and i just wonder i have a wrong start but I stop in the right time.

Comment: Good decision to write it yourself. Having others do your work will make life easier in the short-term - but far, far more difficult in the long-term as you won't have the knowledge/skills/experiences to build upon (especially if this is all for the same class).

Comment: I voted to close this as "needs more information", because you're *not explaining why the heck you did any of this.*

Comment: @djechlin I am confused -- I don't see any close vote on this question, and you don't seem to have the 3k reputation needed to cast one.

Comment: I voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking" because the OP did not explain whether he ever read the bought essay and used it when he wrote his own. Note that my close reason is different from what @djechlin says.

Comment: @scaaahu in a comment, the OP said he didn't even look at the bought essay. I'll edit it in the question.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think he just flagged it.

Comment: @Davidmh I retracted my close vote. Thanks for the editing.

Comment: Whether or not it _actually_ constitutes cheating, it certainly has the potential to _appear_ to be cheating.  If the instructor discovered that you purchased the essay, they might reasonably refuse to believe your claim that you never read it, based on their past experience with essay-buyers.  And why should they?  **I strongly recommend _not_ posting this question under your real name.**

Comment: @DSKekaha It could well be attempted murder if you can be shown to have had someone specific in mind while buying them. In the US, that might count as a "substantial step" toward attempting a killing, which is enough to make an attempt if you document your intention.

Comment: @Tiercelet: Um, no. No one has ever been convicted for attempted murder for simply buying a weapon, regardless of what they were thinking when they bought it.

Comment: @DSKekaha The way things are going right now in the US - soon the act of simply purchasing a gun/ammo could land you in trouble ;P

Comment: The OP had a change of heart, people.  He did the right and best thing given that he bought the paper and given that nothing will change the past.  No one can at all times imagine (or be aware of) and prevent all negative consequences that might occur somewhere as a result of each of his/her actions, unless that person were to have a preternatural supra-caffeinated vigilance (and even so, the world would grind to a halt of thinking, fear, and inaction).  I wish the typical person here had an intuitive understanding of this.

Comment: Certainly, keep a copy of the essay you purchased, so that you can use it to demonstrate the multitude of ways in which you have not copied from it, if required.  But surely the purpose of writing an essay is to show that you've exerted your own mind in grappling with the subject?  Why would it not be *encouraged* to go and read a whole bunch of other essays as part of preparation for writing your own?  That would be entirely appropriate research in my universe (which is not an academic one, so don't trust me on it).

Comment: @DavidBullock Searching for, reading, and critically evaluating a bunch of related sources, and then doing the difficult work of applying what you've learned to the particular assignment, is appropriate. Commissioning an essay that exactly addresses your assignment, so that you don't have to do the work of finding research material and reinterpreting it in the context of your assignment, is not.

Comment: No, you didn't turn it in. Unless you decide to date the essay you purchases and you were already dating another person. Or if by essay, they meant esé , then you purchased a person and that is illegal and you cheated the system.

Comment: @DSKekaha See, e.g., [Kansas' definition of attempt](http://kslegislature.org/li_2012/b2011_12/statute/021_000_0000_chapter/021_053_0000_article/021_053_0001_section/021_053_0001_k/), including, "An attempt is any overt act toward the perpetration of a crime done by a person who intends to commit such crime but ... or [is] intercepted in executing such crime." If they can prove you bought a gun in order to kill (say, you said so to police), but you couldn't because you got arrested, that's attempted murder in KS. IDK if there are actual cases. Doesn't apply to OP, since he changed his mind.

Answer (score 48):

If your task is to write an essay and you let somebody do it for you, then you are cheating. If you copy somebody's work (even just a part of it) then you are cheating. If you try to let somebody's work pass as your own, then you are cheating.

You are saying that you are *not using their work* – I hope that means that you are not using their text (in total or parts of it), you have not just obfuscated the text and try to pass it as your own, or have not rewritten the essay in your own words (keeping the ideas and golden thread of the bought essay). If this is true, then (at least in my courses) you would not be a cheater. In all these cases you could replace the bought essay with the essay of a classmate and we would have a very similar question. The only difference is that you have paid money for it.

Comment: I did that essay 100% by my own, I just paid but NOT using ANY word in the bought essay

Comment: @AntoniNguyen Here it's important to distinguish between words and ideas. If you have just rewritten the whole essay using your own words but keeping the flow of arguments and ideas, then you are cheating. If however you have independently written the essay, then you are good to go.

Comment: About the Essay. I'm not even read the bought essay. My question is PAID for a writer is already cheating or i'm cheater only when i use thier work ?

Comment: If you have not read it, then you have done nothing wrong. Here, we would  would not consider this as cheating.

Comment: However, you should keep in mind that people may think it's evidence of cheating since if it was found out you'd hired someone then it would be hard for you to prove you didn't use it (depending on how similar the essays are).

Comment: i'm ready if they compare 2 essays (mine and the bought one).

Comment: @Antoni: You bought the essay but didn't read any of it?  If true, then you have **clearly not cheated**: an academic essay is not a controlled substance such that merely purchasing it can get you in trouble.  On the other hand that someone would buy an essay in this situation and not read it will sound rather unlikely to many (perhaps also to me...).  Given that what you claim you did is totally kosher but *sounds* a bit suspicious, assuming everything you said is true I would advise you to simply keep quiet about the entire situation.

Comment: @TimB That shouldn't be too hard to prove.  Present both essays.

Comment: @gerrit and it's likely there are similarities between them. How similar they are or are not is down to luck. What happens if they quote the same passages or take the same overall direction? In this case people will tend to assume you copied rather than it being a co-incidence since you have already shown an intent to cheat and only have your word that you did not go through with it.

Comment: @flo how are you distinguishing 'reading' from 'research'? How is this different from asking a friend or colleague their opinion?

Comment: The line gets pretty fuzzy if you read the illicit essay and then write your own - is it cheating if I pay someone to assist me in research, and they provide me with an outline of the things they've found? Maybe, maybe not. Some professors would likely consider it cheating regardless of circumstances. Some professors are OK with students working together on their homework, others would consider that cheating. Much as hard and fast rules are easy to define, they're hard to apply in every circumstance.

Comment: Is it cheating to ask somebody to help you? Is it cheating to ask your professor for a hint and then use it when doing the task? Is it cheating to pay your professor to give you a hint (well, not that he'd let you, but let's skip that)? Is it cheating to pay someone else to give you hints? Answers depends on many things. But you don't even need to answer. When the fact of your theoretical cheating comes into the game, usually it will not be you to decide whether it was allowed or not. I'm not sure if discussing it "in general" has any real value to you.

Comment: @Gusdor In this context reading is a part of research. Reading is necessary to get an overview of a field or to get the newest results. The same is true for talking to colleagues or friends. The research comes after that and tries to improve known results or find new interesting ideas. Again you can ask colleagues and friends for advise (just give credit where credit is due). The main difference is that for **me** doing research related to the word _new_ while reading is related to the word _known_.

Comment: @Jason if it was cheating to write your own essay after reading the illicit one in order to better understand how to write an essay on the field, that would mean that in order to publish academically, one would have to cite every article one has ever read, even years ago and half-remembered as if in a dream - because reading articles, understanding their flow and style, etc. is a major way we learn how to write an article! Surely, there's a difference between "reading an essay in order to build or improve essay-writing skills" and "plagiarism".

Comment: @quetzalcoatl doesn't "pay someone else to give you hints" mean the same thing as "hire a private tutor"? That's not (usually) cheating.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - Whether or not you can make a case for it is irrelevant.  What matters is how your professor, and the administrative bureaucratic construct above them, will react if they found out. Buying a completed essay is considered poor academic practice, shady at best, if you don't use it to plagiarize that's all well and good but you've already compromised yourself with the first act. That may be unrecoverable. If you just want an essay form, you could have bought an essay on an unrelated topic, or gone to any of the journals available to your department. Tutors are accepted practice.

Answer (score 34):

In the normal flow of using paid essay-writing service, the point at which the cheating actually occurs is when you try to pass off someone else's work as your own - in other words, when you submit the essay that wasn't written by you. So if you didn't do that, then it's not cheating.

Except... you may have used the essay that was written for you as inspiration for writing your own essay. If the conditions of the assignment say that you are not allowed to receive this sort of outside help, then it is cheating. Otherwise, it could be fine, but you would probably be ethically required to acknowledge the help you received from the essay-writer. If you fail to do so, that is academic fraud of some sort - it may not technically fall under the umbrella of "cheating" but I'd say it's still pretty bad, and will probably be dealt with similarly.

(So to summarize, I've identified three Bad Things to do: pass off someone else's work as your own, use someone else's work in violation of the terms of the assignment, or fail to acknowledge assistance you received.)

As a separate issue, consider that even though you didn't actually cheat, you gave money to a company that exists primarily to facilitate cheating. So perhaps you have indirectly supported other people's ability to cheat. It's up to you whether you're okay with that.

Comment: Take cheating on a test.  If you provide your answers for some other student to copy, have you cheated even if they refuse to use those answers?  If the professor catches you sharing them, so that no one gets a chance to copy them, do you think you'll be able to say "Well it wasn't cheating since no one used them?"

Comment: Chalk the spent money up to a mistake. They happen. Can't crucify him for that, and there's no undoing it.

Comment: @Alizter It is radically and completely different from that.

Comment: @Lawtonfogle: not that the criminal law is relevant except as a general framework for ethics, but at least in English-based common law if you are ready to commit a criminal act but are prevented by law enforcers, then you can be guilty of the inchoate offence of "attempt". If you change your mind and don't go through with it then you aren't (although you could perhaps be guilty of consipracy if you've agreed with someone else to commit the crime). So it's reasonable to refuse the excuse that you were caught in the act, but accept the excuse of deciding against the "crime" of cheating.

Comment: ... naturally it's best from the POV of prosecution, to let someone carry through the act before stepping in, since then there's less to prove. But in the case of a student sharing answers you probably don't want to give them the opportunity to take others down with them. Easiest would probably be just to define in an academic conduct policy that offering answers to others is in itself an offence regardless of whether anyone takes them. But if you actively decide not to do that then actually yes I think you should accept "nobody used them" as a defence.

Answer (score 15):

## My general answer.

I would pipe in with the general consensus: *usually, paying for an essay that you never use is **not** cheating.* I feel like people who are saying "well, you funded the cheating industry" have a somewhat valid point: you probably don't have warrant to feel *proud* about what you did and might even feel *bad* about it. But the question of "cheating" is, "**did this give you an unfair advantage over the other students**," and in the usual case, that is "no."

However, please note that a **university policy** on cheating may forbid things which are not themselves cheating! The classic example is if, after you've taken a course, you write an essay for someone who is currently taking it: you might be kicked out for *helping someone cheat* even though you didn't cheat yourself. Your university's policy may also ban paying for essays *even if you don't use them* as a matter of course. So if we're not talking about "cheating" but "violating the policy on cheating" then we need to know the policy.

## Now let's get clever.

To me this is actually a **fun** question insofar as we ask, "well, what about that word *usually* up there: you said it's not *usually* cheating, but how **unusual** can we make this?" In other words: are there situations where you can pay for an essay that you will never read or submit, and you still somehow use it to cheat? And the answer is **yes.**

As a vehicle to explore this, I would like to introduce you to Dr. Alicia Alice, who teaches at the University of Cheating (named for the city it is in, of course). Her course is in Advanced Floozels -- do not worry about this word, it is a nonsense word. Unbeknownst to her, lots of her students are rather amenable to cheating in principle.

Dr. Alice has a very strange policy for her Advanced Floozels course: since nobody can truly memorize everything there is to know about floozels, her final exam begins with one essay question: students must, in a 24 hour time period, research the given question and write an essay response. She wants to give them some ability to study for the exam by guiding their general research on floozels, so one week prior to revealing the question, she reveals 10 possible essay questions, one of which is going to be the chosen question. Let's also say that there are 30 students, with the top 10 getting a significant boost on their actual final exam and the bottom 10 getting a significant penalty.

#### Bob and the random testing insurance

Bob only finds a small niche of floozel knowledge interesting. When the study week begins, he only really likes one of the questions, so he buys the 9 remaining essays from people who have taken Advanced Floozels before, for each of the other questions, and then he spends a week studying only the one question that interests him. Bob is very lucky: Dr. Alice chooses this question for the exam, he writes a perfect essay with eight whole days' research behind it, and he rockets into the top bracket.

Bob has gained an unfair advantage over the other students even though he did not read or submit the 9 papers he paid for.

#### Carol's curvy screw-up

Carol and Dennis are also taking Advanced Floozels and Dennis wants to spend the test day goofing off, even though he is a great student. He offers in advance to pay Carol, another good student, for her essay, so that he can rewrite it in his own words and try to pass off his essay as independent work. Initially, Carol accepts his money and agrees. However, when the essay question is revealed, she chickens out and wants to return the money. Unfortunately, Dennis is out whitewater rafting and she is unable to reach him by phone or text to retroactively decline the offer. She therefore instead approaches her friend Ellie, who now does some floozel research. It turns out that the question is very similar to Ellie's research from last year and so Ellie offers to write (for some of Dennis's money) a paper which looks to Dennis like it is cutting-edge research but which Dr. Alice will realize is total garbage. Carol agrees.

This is not always cheating, but we could maybe expect that Dennis would get a slightly better paper in than Carol's, so if Carol was just between two of these categories (bottom 10 gets penalized, middle 10 is neutral, top 10 is rewarded), tanking Dennis might give her a reward that she wouldn't have otherwise had, had she not agreed to this whole strange state-of-affairs.

#### Anonymous exams which the instructor nevertheless reads.

There are a lot of ways to cheat if we broaden the "I didn't submit it" to "I didn't submit it *in my own name*." For example, we can do "insurance" this way too: Felipe might pay for and submit a nameless exam and then intentionally not write his own name on his exam. He does this because he's taking a very difficult risk on his own paper, writing about some very cutting-edge floozel research that will either be extremely forward-thinking to Alice, or else will seem like complete drivel. Now when she has a paper with no name, the compassionate Dr. Alice grades both normally and posts both publicly, and expects them to get back to her. Felipe looks at the nameless posts and sees that his paper, in fact, has the highest grade there, so he claims it as his own and apologizes for not writing his name on his essay; perhaps she even asks him to prove it and he shows her the original file on his laptop.

Other people claim their papers and Dr. Alice has no idea who the 31st paper belongs to, and cannot necessarily prove that anybody was cheating. Nevertheless, we know that Felipe was: similar to Bob, he was buying a "safety net" which other students did not have access to.

Or, Gertrude might buy so many low-quality papers and submit them anonymously that Dr. Alice realizes that something has gone awfully wrong, and might ask everyone to privately email her their submissions from their school email account instead, since that will be better-tied to their identity. Gertrude uses the extra time from this distraction to gain an unfair advantage over other people who have completed their essay on-time.

Harold pays for an anonymous essay which ultimately insinuates that if Dr. Alice failed any of her male students, she would be subjected to physical danger. The police are unable to trace it and she is scared enough that she doesn't fail any of them, and then Harold has an unfair advantage over the female students. (Technically this doesn't have to be submitted, but it happens to be the best way to ensure Dr. Alice or one of her TAs reads the work.)

Irene pays for an essay in the sense that she pays someone else to steal some early drafts of several essays from some of the top people in the class, with the explicit essay being composed of complete sentences from all of them weaved into a cohesive narrative. She does not read them directly but anonymously posts it to FloozelTalk, the premier floozel research chat forum, where Dr. Alice reads it and thinks it's cutting edge research being done as we speak. Dr. Alice penalizes everyone who appears to have plagiarized this essay, and Irene thereby gets some benefit from it.

#### Then there are the ones which go outside the box completely.

Implicit in this I have been looking for solutions which use the *information content* of the paper but, I mean, it's also a physical artifact as well. Jacob pays for an essay which is 300 pages long (needing it to be a coherent essay just in case someone stops him and demands to see it, for example) -- and then he rigs it above the turn-in slot so that he drops it on Dr. Alice's head as she is picking up the papers, knocking her out cold: he then anonymously calls an ambulance and uses the added time that she is recovering in the hospital to complete his actual essay.

Comment: Your example with Bob is not convincing to me.  He has set up a situation in which no matter what happens he *could* gain an unfair advantage, but in the actual outcome, he ends up studying hard and doing well.  But for all we know, if one of the other nine topics came up, Bob could have -- and arguably, should have -- a last minute change of heart.

Comment: You seem to want to convict Bob of cheating for his *intention to cheat* but that's not the way things work.  Suppose instead Bob decides to assassinate a favored, incumbent presidential candidate assuming they win the election, the chances of which are regarded as 90%.  Bob makes considerable preparations including buying plane tickets, firearms and so forth.  It turns out the other candidate wins and Bob stays home.  What crime are you going to accuse him of?  (I didn't read all of your other scenarios, but the last seems more appropriate for a humor site than an academic advice website.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Preparation of a crime can be illegal in some cases (e.g. conspiracy to murder). Considering example with Bob, suppose he doesn't know much about exam subject Y, and brings a covert cheat sheet. Subject Y does not come up on the exam. Even though he did not use his cheat sheet, I contend he still cheated because (if you view the subjects that come up on the exam as random events) his expected value for the exam was higher than that of students who did not make such preparations. OP had "insurance" of being able to hand in the paid-for paper if his own turned out substandard.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I'm not convicting Bob for his *intention to cheat*, but saying that *he cheated*, if cheating is defined as gaining an unfair advantage. So there are only two ways you can say he didn't cheat: either (a) he didn't gain an advantage or (b) his actions were fair. I regard (a) as a no-brainer: if it weren't an advantage he wouldn't have paid for it, and there is no real question that if he hadn't bought the essays his behavior would have changed and his essay would be worse for it. So then there's (b), was his advantage fair? No: he didn't work for it. Ergo, he cheated: the end.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark but if you are interested in the philosophy of such things they are called "counterfactuals"; insurance that goes unclaimed provides a counterfactual benefit, for example: it's still a real benefit (as long as the insurance is appropriately priced) which you'll pay for, but sometimes it does go unclaimed. Yes, there is a strong temptation in all of us at some point or another to neglect counterfactuals, but they seem persistent, hard to shake, and crucial to understanding things like causation.

Comment: @Chris: I disagree and, speaking as a faculty member, find it very unlikely that a student would be convicted of cheating under this situation.  The flaw in your reasoning is (a): he has only gained an unfair advantage if you accept as given *what he will do* in other situations.  If a student had cheated similarly in the past, then it might be reasonable to assume this is part of a larger "conspiracy".  But on an individual level you really cannot convict people for what they might have been planning to do.  Of course the example is also very contrived...it will probably never actually arise.

Comment: @Tom: Again, expected value computations are predicated on the assumption that something will happen in every given case.  They are appropriate and vitally useful in many contexts but work badly in determining guilt.  Legal experts know well that criminal conspiracy charges must be applied sensibly: in the example I gave, there is no way that one action would lead to conviction.  If you had similarly murdered nine people and cancelled one trip in the past, that would be different.  Finally, bringing a cheat sheet to an exam is by definition against the rules whether you look at it or not.

Comment: By the way, cheating is **not** defined as "gaining an unfair advantage", since there is no systematic way of evaluating which advantages are fair.  Is it fair that some students think more quickly than others or have prior background in the area or have parents who are experts in the subject or who have access to private tutors or....In actual universities cheating is defined much more specifically as breaking the rules of an assignment or exam.

Comment: The difference here is that you are concerned with whether *he would be convicted of cheating* (which depends on the university code, how sympathetic his listeners are, and whether he is caught) whereas I am purely concerned with whether *he cheated*, which is a much simpler question (did he gain an advantage; if so, was it unfair?). I can answer the latter definitively and your statement "I disagree" doesn't address the whole "here are the two defining criteria, and he meets both." Rather, you are stating that not all cheaters are punished, and I agree wholeheartedly with *that*.

Comment: I mean, you can be nihilistic about fairness, sure. That doesn't bother me in the slightest.

Comment: @Chris: No, I am concerned with whether a student would be regarded by his institution of having committed academic dishonesty: this is what the OP asked about, and this is the appropriate notion of "cheating" for academia.se.  You seem to be asking whether a student behaved unethically...but not *this* student; instead you are picking cases precisely because they create interesting ethical questions.  That sounds more like philosophy.se.  Not getting carried away with philosophical reasoning is actually rather important in dealing with actual students an academics.

Comment: Final comment: if your point is "Is it possible to imagine a situation in which a student could buy a paper, not read it, and in which those with perfect knowledge of the situation would know that the student was behaving unethically in so doing?  Yes." then I do agree.

Comment: "either (a) he didn't gain an advantage [...] (a) as a no-brainer: if it weren't an advantage he wouldn't have paid for it" This is a non-sequitur. If I intend to eat and buy a meal for this purpose, but then throw the meal away without taking a bite, I didn't eat. It would be an advantage if he actually used what he paid for, but he says he did not use it in any way.

Comment: @G.Bach Straw man. I'm not saying he "bought a meal to eat it" but rather that he insured himself against a future which would wreck him, so that it would merely injure him. I am saying the fact that people will pay for insurance reveals that it has positive utility for those people. And that's no non-sequitur: it's a standard way of figuring out what peoples' utilities are, called in its most abstract "revealed preference." I mean, you can view insured people as irrational because you think counterfactual thinking is bogus, sure: unfortunately you will probably enjoy insurance at some point.

Comment: Not a strawman, because the direct analogy would be not claiming insurance money.

Comment: It's only an unfair advantage if there's some circumstance under which he would have used it. It's possible that he buys his insurance essays, the teacher assigns his least-favorite topic, then he decides he's better than cheating and writes his own essay. He might have actually given himself a *dis*advantage if he didn't bother to study the other topics. This Bob has not cheated. If we know Bob would have used the other essays, then I agree he cheated. There's some probability of using the essays that gives neither advantage nor disadvantage. Anything above this is cheating.

Comment: I'd like to point out a slightly more tangible benefit Bob gained over the others. Having bought 9 essays, he gave himself the ability to spend the entire week researching the one topic in which he was interested, whereas everyone who didn't cheat spent less than one day researching each of the 10 topics throughout the week assuming they studied all 10 questions like they should have if they were wise. This gives Bob a clear advantage because he gets roughly 10x more research in on the topic that's chosen, and even if the professor had chosen another topic he was still ready for it.

Comment: I very much enjoyed reading this scenarios, especially the last few.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to be to a bit presumptuous and say:

#### That's not what you really want to ask.

Are you a cheater, philosophically? Ethically? Morally? Historically? Well, maybe so, maybe no, anybody can voice their opinion. Suppose that you are. Now suppose that you aren't. That has no direct bearing on reality.

I believe what you're really asking is:

1. Should I suppress my feelings of guilt?
2. What will the academic institution I study at do if they ever find out?
3. Will they ever find out?
4. Will I tell them myself or not?
5. Will I be able to feel at peace with my decision about that?

The answer to No. 3 is: Unlikely, since the essay writer will not start blabbing about how he helps people make a mockery of the academic system.

The answer to no. 2 depends on information we don't have.

But all the rest - well, they're really hard questions. I would suggest you talk to a good friend of yours, or your significant other, or your parents, or therapist/counselor, about them.

Answer (score 7):

There seem to be two interpretations of "cheat" here. One refers to academic standards (and is probably what you meant, since you asked on the academia web site); the other refers to general morality. As far as academic standards are concerned, I agree with the others who have answered that you did not cheat.  General morality is another matter.  Even though you never used the essay that you bought, you presumably originally intended to use it, and that intention was immoral.  Fortunately, society in general and academia in particular do not (usually) punish private intentions, only external actions.  So you're OK as far as society and academia are concerned.  On the other hand, you may not be quite OK as far as your own conscience is concerned.  That's a separate issue, and probably off-topic for this site, but I'll tell you what I'd do in your situation: I wouldn't tell my professor or TA or dean or anyone in academia about any of this, but I would mention it the next time I go to confession.

Comment: I think this is the best possible answer to this question.

Comment: You should clarify your final sentence — are you referring to Christian Roman Catholic ceremony? Or something else? Not everybody is of your faith!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Please note that the last sentence of my answer was specifically about "what I'd do in your situation". Other people may well have other ways of dealing with a troubled conscience.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Right, so I'm wondering what you meant by it. What _would_ you do? It's not clear!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would do exactly what I wrote, namely to mention my sin in confession.  In my case, this means confession to a traditional Roman Catholic priest.  (As you pointed out in your previous comment, one can't expect that others would do the same.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thank you, that is the missing detail. The sentence as written assumes a certain audience, you see!

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to distinguish "did you cheat" from "did you violate the rules against cheating".  Interestingly, this answer turns out to be essentially the opposite of the answer by Andreas Blass, although I think that is also very good answer.

If you did not read the essay you purchased, then I would say you did not cheat, in the end, although apparently you intended to cheat originally. That is my personal take, at least,

However, how can you prove you did not read the essay? At my institution, cheating is defined as "Any action that, if the instructor of the course knew about it, would not be permitted." (That is almost a direct quote from the policy.) Certainly, buying an essay would be considered a violation of my school's policy as it is literally written: an instructor would prohibit buying an essay if she knew a student was planning to do it.

I do agree with the conclusion of Andreas' answer: I would not tell anyone at the university about it, but perhaps a discussion with a counselor or religious advisor might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Using a simple and extreme analogy: are you a murderer if you buy a knife but you end up deciding not do anything with it?

Comment: This analogy does not work. Knifes are useful tools, the fact that they can be used for murder is one of many uses. What are the other uses of getting somebody to write an essay for you other than cheating?

Comment: I use to think that but i changed my mind .

Comment: @Alizter To have research material? I was given a task to write an essay, so I went to library and read some reports and books and written my own thoughts on the subject. Have I cheated?

Comment: @luk32 Asking somebody else to write an essay on what you are researching is not you researching.

Comment: @Alizter Well it's poor work if it's the only source. I still would say that I am able to formulate my own thoughts after reading someone's work. IMO it's grey area. What if it became one among other materials. What if one purchased 10 essays on the topic? Do you say that's after reading it it's impossible not to become a cheater? Sounds pretty ridiculous.

Comment: @luk32 However note that 'someone elses work' is also paid for by the party. The work only exists because the party in question asked and paid for it.

Comment: @Alizter Libraries and newspapers also cost money, precisely to provide research materials, reports and opinions. And I guess using it is very encouraged to formulate one's own. I am playing a devil's advocate a bit, but honestly I cannot find very much difference between reading a paid article. If you don't plagiarize it, I guess it's the same. I am not saying it's white. It might be not black though, IMHO.

Comment: Unless the assignment was 'be a librarian for a day' then I do not think the behaviour was ethical.

Comment: If you hire a hitman but stop them before they kill the target, but they then use your money to fund their next attack and this gets proven in a court of law, are you guilty of a crime?  Maybe you aren't guilty of direct murder, but I doubt you would be leaving that courtroom with a clean record.

Comment: Using a simple and extreme analogy: are you an offender if you buy 1 pound of cocaine and never use it? Yes, I know that's controlled substance :) but you now, in some places some knives are controlled too (i.e. blade length limit, and so on). This indicates that buying things or services may be or may be not problematic, and that it depends not only on the kind of goods/service but also location/time/circumstances/...

Comment: @luk32 If you use the essay as a source, then you should cite it as such, to avoid cheating.  However, citing such an essay will look rather suspicious, especially as it is not public.

Comment: @Kimball Haha, yeah that's what I was missing. Sure it's hella weird, but for me it would be ethical. I mean, the work is quite genuine then. It's just like any other source. Imagine having a legitimate work, in terms of originality and plagiarism etc., using and citing such a source. A very interesting casus IMO.

Comment: @Kimball It would look suspicious but it would not be cheating.